# GPU Image Filter

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, gpu, core-image

In my app, I want to apply different video filters  like: Fade in -Out,Snow fall,Rainbow,Fast Motion,Slow Motion,etc.

I study the  Brad Larson project but it does not full fill my all filter requirement.

so, Help me!!

Comment: Please iterate all your requirements so that help can be given in full :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need custom filters you can always write them and add to GPUImage project. Just grab some easy filter like `GPUImageRGBFilter` or `GPUImageLineGenerator` and experiment.

You can also modify `OpenGL` calls directly to inject your custom effects in front of a movie. Take a look at CubeExample.

Comment: but how i do the effect like snow fall??